# Prevent generic type from being overridden in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Need the layoutKey to be of type L (so following the example below it should be of type IOfficiallLevelLayouts), but every time I pass some value into it the type L is being overridden by the type that I'm passing.

[image]
[image]

Currently the ITableEntity looks something like this:

```
interface ITableEntity<T, F, L> {
  entity: BaseEntity<T, F, L>;
  filterDefault?: Partial<T>;
  actions?: IAction[];
  layoutKey?: L;
  onRowClick?: (item: T) => void;
}
```

How to force the layoutKey as type L (IOfficialLevelLayout)?

Comment: Screenshots of your IDE aren't appropriate here, unfortunately. [Please replace images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: The compiler infers the value of type `L` from the usage of the generic type. It is `string` for `'dff'`. How is defined `IOfficialLevelLayout`?

Comment: It looks something like this: type IOfficialLevelLayout = 'layout1' | 'layout2';

Answer (score 1):

Ok managed to fix it by using something like this:

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];
```

So ITableEntity becomes:

```
interface ITableEntity<T, F, L> {
  entity: BaseEntity<T, F, L>;
  filterDefault?: Partial<T>;
  actions?: IAction[];
  layoutKey?: NoInfer<L>;
  onRowClick?: (item: T) => void;
}
```